# gspread sh.share not showing up in options list

Tags: gspread

I'm using PyCharm, I've imported gspread successfully into Python (3.10).  Am able to update a Google sheet on Google drive.. Works well.  Want to email spreadsheet using .share.  According to documentation:

```py
sh.share('blah@blah.co.nz', perm_type='user', role='writer')
```

should work but .share not available in drop down list.  The drop down list displays a whole bunch of items but no .share option. I've download and imported the lastest version of gspread. I'm thinking that the .share functionality may not be running in this version or am I doing something wrong? looking at other help messages, .share is being used by others. Any comments? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you have imported the latest version of gspread then (as of today) it should be version 5.4.0 and the documentation for that version for that method is: [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/spreadsheet.html#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.share)

If you look at the code in the same version it is: [here too](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/4fcad2ad3ebea34737f631d53ef3ce0ca719e35e/gspread/spreadsheet.py#L475) and the method is called `share`. But it is in the `spreadsheet` object.

So it should be used like this:

```py
...
sph = client.open("my_spreadsheet")
sph.share('blah@blah.co.nz', perm_type='user', role='writer')
```